# Mocking of RestTemplate is with spring boot 2.x is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am writing a unit test for my service layer which calls a REST backend service and MongoDB. But when executing my test in local working fine but when package my app in my CICD pipeline during compile time its try to run Unit tests while doing so getting null pointer exceptions when using `RestTemplate` and `MongoTemplate` beans.

```
MyTestService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemlate mongoTemplate;

    public String callDBAndBackend() {

        // some business logic
        UpdatedObject mongoDoc = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(updateObject);

        restTemplate.exchange(reqEntity, ResponseObject.class);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
MyTestServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    @InjectMocks
    private MyTestService myTestService;

    @Test
    public void testCallDBAndBackend() {

        when(restTemplate.exchange(reqEntity, ResponseObject.class)).thenReturn("Success"); // In this line getting Null pointer. Cant able to inject restTemplate
        when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(updateObject)).thenReturn("Success"); // In //this line getting Null pointer. Cant able to inject mongoTemplate

    myTestService.callDBAndBackend();

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
    <!--    <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>  -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When compiling this code I am getting RestTemplate  and MongoTemplate object as null which is causing NPL. If I run the same code from IDE its working fine and getting valid RestTemplate and MongoTemplate mock objects.

Comment: Can you add the imports of your test class? Is it possible that you mix JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 within the same test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InjectMocks` annotation to your target class `MyTestService` to inject the mocked objects.

Your solution should give you NLP because you didn't provide the mocked objects to the `MyTestService`

i.e

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
MyTestServiceTest{

@InjectMocks
private MyTestService service;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Test
public void testCallDBAndBackend() {
    // Arrange
    when(restTemplate.exchange(reqEntity,ResponseObject.class))
    .thenReturn("Success");
    when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(updateObject)).thenReturn("Success");

     // Act
     String actual = service.callDBAndBackend();

     // Assert
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question with '@'InjectMock annotation but still im getting same issue. Here the issue is somehow I am not been able to get Spring specific beans in my UnitTesting context while build.Same is working fine if individually execute my code from my IDE. I suspect spring dependent beans are not available to the testing context during build time.Same kind of code is working fine with Junit4